# Can I get APP_KEY and SECURE_KEY from Dropbox API directly, e.t.c. keep user blind?

Tags: java, dropbox-api, code-access-security

I need to create application with single file storage. But I need to upload/download files with simple functionality, in way something like that: user install application, simply enter login and password and he gets immediately operations to upload and download files.
Is it possible to get security keys from DropBox API programmably?

Comment: That's a very bad idea.  Users should **never** enter a password into any other site or program.

Comment: ...but if user need get access to his account? When using DropBox API I need to enter app_key and secure_key, without them I can't operate! However I can't give user another problem to enter additional secure information.

Comment: question leads in other way - is there any possibility to get those security keys directly from DropBox site without user? for now i haven't found an answer... help)

Comment: Use their OAuth process. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some confusion about how authentication to the Dropbox API works.

The **app key** and corresponding secret should be for your app, so you would either keep those on your server if you're building a web app, or you would embed those in your app if it's a mobile or other client. Each user of your app needs to log in via OAuth, which will give you an **access token** and corresponding secret. You'll use the access token and secret along with your app key and secret to access files in a user's Dropbox.

I hope that helps. If not, could you clarify more in your question?

Comment: That helps! Thank you, smarx!) Can you tell me, is there a difference between registration of PC app and mobile app on DropBox? Because if you register app from mobile it doesn't ask you to enter any APP_KEY and SECURE_KEY

Comment: Interesting moment! If you download DropBox app and use it, app doesn't require entering secure keys and automatically register itself in DropBox account/My applications.

Comment: sorry for my english, if i couldn't formulate my thoughts well)

Comment: You as a user never need to enter an app key and app secret... those are part of the app. So the mobile app has an app key and secret, and it uses those when it connects to your Dropbox. Similarly, an app that *you* build will have an app key and secret and will use those to connect to a user's Dropbox.